# Show that $h$ is entire and $f$ is a constant function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=\{Z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$. Suppose $f:\overline D\to\mathbb{C}$ is continuous, holomorphic in $D$, and $f(\partial D)\subset \mathbb{R}$. Define $h:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ by 
$$
  h(z)=\begin{cases}
               f(z) &\text{if}\ z\in \overline D\\
               \overline{f(1/\overline z)} &\text{if}\ z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus \overline{D}
            \end{cases}$$
Show that $h$ is entire and $f$ is a constant function.

My work: I can show that $h$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \overline{D}$.

To show $h$ is entire, by using Morera's theorem, considering arbitrary triangular path, the integral of $h$ is zero if it does not cross the boundary of the unit disc, however, what if the triangular path cross the unit disc? How to show in this case the integral is also zero.

Could anyone kindly help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A different approach: Write $f=u+iv.$ Then $v$ is harmonic on $\mathbb D,$ continuous on $\overline {\mathbb D},$ and equals $0$ on $\partial D.$ From the maximum principle for harmonic functions, $v\equiv 0.$ Thus $f$ is holomorphic and real in $\mathbb D,$ which implies $f$ is constant in $\mathbb D.$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Consider the case of a "triangle" (either inside the closed disk or outside the open disk) having an arc of the circle as one of its sides. Show using uniform continuity that the integral is $0$. For a general triangle crossing the unit circle, divide it into smaller "triangles," two of which fit the case we just considered.